# Conditional statement shortcut (python)

Tags: python, if-statement

I cannot find where my professor taught us to do this. For a conditional statement, if there are multiple numbers ("if x = 1 or 3 or 5 or 9 or ......), how do I make it shorter so I dont have to type every single one? I thought it was the in function???

this is what exactly im trying to do:

elif month == 1 and day == in[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]:
print("January", day + "th", year, "is a valid date")

Comment: It's not `day == in[4,5,...]` but `day in [4,5,...]`. And why not use `day >= 4 and day <= 30`?

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through a list and check each time if one of them is equal to day:

```
days = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10...] #And so on.
for i in days:
    if month == 1 and day == i:
        print("January", i, "th", year, "is a valid date")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if variable is in range from `x` to `y`, than you can write this code:

```
if day in range(x, y + 1):
    # some code
```

Note that we add `1` to 2nd argument to `range` function because range covers numbers from 1st argument to 2nd argument - 1